# Faster, higher, stronger

Tags: knowledge, geography, anagram

Last week my local newspaper featured a crossword puzzle.
Two things were strange about it: it was placed on the sports pages
and the clues were numbered in a very peculiar way, with what looks like a country code added to each clue.
I think I was able to solve all clues, but I still couldn't find the final answer…

Below is a copy of the crossword, maybe you can give it a shot.
I might add that -57 is a bit of a mean one, because the words it clues don't exist, but I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out.

> [image: Crossword]
>
> ### Across
>
> -89^ (NED): Public transport vehicles gone crazy (3,5)
>   -85* (USA): Chose everyone (6,3)
>   -49* (FRA): Femur or fibula (3,4)
>   -45^ (GER): Scream Artist (5)
>   -41^ (CAN): Not a warning (2,5)
>   -41* (AUT): Stone for a sister (3,5)
>   -85^ (USA): The deficit of a bird of prey (5,4)
>   -25* (FRA): Trustworthy television (8,2)
>   -65* (NOR): Informal British toilet (3)
>
> ### Down
>
> -1^ (BRA): E in Roadie, H in Hairdo, N in Ordain or T in Adroit (5,6)
>   -25^^ (ESP): No trucks and buses are allowed on this road (3,4)
>   -113^ (USA): American home ground (2,4)
>   -7** (CAN): A small bay for a small truck (3,4)
>   -57** (USA): Devoweled dale of Latin waters (5,4)
>   -5^ (GBR): Missing in country for men (2,3)
>   -105^ (SWE): Leave some open (4,4)
>   -29^ (KOR): Don Cornelius created a train for it (4)

Comment: Are you sure, **all** of them are Cryptic clues? Some of them definitely are, but I am not sure, all of them are.

Comment: I've removed the [cryptic-crosswords] tag: none of these are cryptics.

Comment: Yeah, not the right tag, sorry about that, didn't mean to lead anyone in the wrong direction :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The country name is a clue to the answer because

> All the answers are anagrams of a city in that country that hosted the Olympic Games, minus one or two letters (number determined by the number of symbols following the clue)

-89^ (NED): Public transport vehicles gone crazy (3,5)

> MAD TRAMS ==> AMST(E)RDAM

-85* (USA): Chose everyone (6,3)

> PICKED ALL ==> LAKE PL(A)CID

-49* (FRA): Femur or fibula (3,4)

> LEG BONE ==> G(R)ENOBLE

-45^ (GER): Scream Artist (5)

> MUNCH ==> MUN(I)CH

-41^ (CAN): Not a warning (2,5)

> NO ALERT ==> (M)ONTREAL

-41* (AUT): Stone for a sister (3,5)

> NUN BRICK ==> INN(S)BRUCK

-85^ (USA): The deficit of a bird of prey (5,4)

> EAGLE LOSS ==> LOS A(N)GELES

-25* (FRA): Trustworthy television (8,2)

> RELIABLE TV ==> A(L)BERTVILLE

-65* (NOR): Informal British toilet (3)

> LOO ==> O(S)LO

Down

-1^ (BRA): E in Roadie, H in Hairdo, N in Ordain or T in Adroit (5,6)

> RADIO JOINER ==> RIO D(E) JANEIRO (Thanks to @MichaelSeifert & @MOehm)

-25^^ (ESP): No trucks and buses are allowed on this road (3,4)

> CAR LANE ==> (B)ARCEL(O)NA

-113^ (USA): American home ground (2,4)

> US SOIL ==> S(T) LOUIS

-7** (CAN): A small bay for a small truck (3,4)

> VAN COVE ==> VANCO(U)VE(R)

-57** (USA): Devoweled dale of Latin waters (5,4)

> AQUAS VLLY ==> SQUA(W) VALL(E)Y (Thanks to @IanMacDonald)

-5^ (GBR): Missing in country for men (2,3)

> NO OLD ==> LONDO(N) (Thanks to @MOehm)

-105^ (SWE): Leave some open (4,4)

> LOCK MOST ==> STOCK(H)OLM

-29^ (KOR): Don Cornelius created a train for it (4)

> SOUL ==> S(E)OUL

Using the clue "Order what's missing chronologically", we

> order the clues based on the year of the Olympics in that city and list the missing letters in that order. (Thanks @MOehm for the missing piece to clear ambiguities!) This gives: THE ANSWER IS MELBOURNE

This gives the final answer as:

> -61 (AUS) because the Melbourne, Australia games were in 1956, 61 years ago.

Comment: AQUAE \_L\_\_ => SQUAW VALLEY

Comment: @IanMacDonald I think the fifth letter has to be S. But this is still helpful, thanks!

Comment: Aha; you're right. I read Los Angeles as the answer by mistake.

Comment: The answer to -1^ is "ADROI JOINER" (since by "joining" each given letter to the letters ADROI, you get an anagram of the given word.)

Comment: -1^ is Radio Joiner (Rio de janeiro + E).

Comment: @MOehm:  Ah, I didn't even see that you could rearrange ADROI to make a word.  That's nicer than my answer.

Comment: Radio is the word that fits the cross clues.

Comment: It also fits with the existing crossing letters. `:)` But you've added an explanation and I haven't.

Comment: And 5^ is NO OLD, because it's missing in "No Country for Old Men". That fits the crosser and makes the missing letter an N instead of an L. It also makes the last word of the solution Melbourne.

Comment: And you've picked the K from Lake Placid, although that's in the answer for -85*. The extra letter here is A, and that makes the first part of the solution "The answer is ...". The order of the Games is clear, even if a city has hosted them twice: The -5, for example, means five year ago and refer to London 2012. An asterisk (snowflake) marks Winter Games, the caret Summer Games.

Comment: You've got it, nice work!